# How to 'filter' an array of structs in Hive without exploding?

Tags: hive, hiveql

Suppose I have this data in a Hive table:

```
fname | lname | records |
------|-------|---------|
 John |  Doe  | [{"name": "John", "lname": "Doe", "age": 55}, {"name": "Jacky", "lname": "Collins", "age": 67}] |
 Jane |  Doe  | [{"name": "John", "lname": "Doe", "age": 55}, {"name": "Jacky", "lname": "Collins", "age": 67}] |
```

I want to get the `records.age` for the matching `fname` and `lname` without exploding `records` column. Is there a way to do this?

Result would be:

```
fname | lname | age  |
------|-------|------|
 John |  Doe  | 55   |
 Jane |  Doe  | NULL |
```

Comment: are  you sure about your expected result ? how come jane's age is null?

Comment: @KoushikRoy I think so. Because Jane Doe is not in `records` column.